# Get max score and name in multiple column based on enum value with group by date

Tags: mysql, enums

[image]

We have sector column of type enum value is ['Midfielder', 'Forward', 'Defender', 'Goalkeeper'].

We want out put like max score of each sector and player name of each sector group by date.

if data is not preset on any date then we want to null or 0.

```
date       │ mid_score │ midfielder │ def_score │ defender
2017-12-26 │ 91        │ Dele Alli  │ 74         │ Jan Vertonghen
2017-12-27 │ 61        │ Eric Dier  │ 68         │ maya yoshida
```

Comment: This is an excellent read. You should consider `varchar` as the column type in place of `enum`. http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregation query you want here would be grouping by the `date` and `sector`, and then finding the max score for that group.  We can place this query into a subquery, and then join your table to it, on the condition that the date, sector, and score match the date, sector, and max score from the subquery.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT date, sector, MAX(score) AS max_score
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY date, sector
) t2
    ON t1.date = t2.date AND
       t1.sector = t2.sector AND
       t1.score = t2.max_score
ORDER BY
    t1.date,
    t1.sector;
```

With regard to missing data, one option to handle that would be to use a calendar table.  That would be slightly too big to fit in an answer, I think, but I will leave that as homework for you.

**Edit:** If you want a single row for each date, then we can do a second rollup on the outer query by date:

```
SELECT
    t1.date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t1.sector ORDER BY t1.score) sectors,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t1.score ORDER BY t1.score) scores
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT date, sector, MAX(score) AS max_score
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY date, sector
) t2
    ON t1.date = t2.date AND
       t1.sector = t2.sector AND
       t1.score = t2.max_score
GROUP BY
    t1.date
ORDER BY
    t1.date;
```

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid No...inner vs. left should not make a difference, because the information in the subquery is guaranteed to be in the outer query.  The OP is saying that on a certain date, a given sector may be missing entirely.  However, in this case the OP still wants to report zero.  It needs a big ugly calendar table, maybe even joins of several tables, and given that the OP showed little effort, I have little motivation to answer further.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thanks for the update, let me read your answers now.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Oh yuck...if so then I'm definitely out :-)

Comment: But i want data with group by date... so in short i want result like. on date 26   which player have max score and sector middlefiler and which player have max score with sector defender. 
so name of the player along with the score..
so output 4 column for each date

Comment: @pravindabhi Then add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: SELECT date, 
MAX(CASE sector WHEN 'Midfielder' THEN score ELSE 0 END) as midfielder, 
MAX(CASE sector WHEN 'Forward' THEN score ELSE 0 END) as forward,  
MAX(CASE performance_buzz.sector WHEN 'Defender' THEN performance_buzz.score ELSE 0 END) as defender

FROM `performance_buzz` GROUP BY date

From above query i have get only max score for each sector not name

Comment: @pravindabhi That is _not_ the query in my answer.  Did you even try to run my code?

Comment: Yes i have tried but output not like what i want.. above query is i just for reference i have tried.

Comment: How many max scores are there per date?  One score, or does each sector have a max score per date?

Comment: Thanks, its working..
But will it be possible to return each date data in one row.. currently it return 4 rows for each date with different sector.

Comment: @pravindabhi You can group my first answer by date, and the use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get a CSV list of sectors and scores.